# Processing 2,2,1 java. Reset position if inside 3d shape

Tags: java, position, processing, reset

i have made this code,with a 3d model,the model starts dismorph after 100 frames.I have a box shape that is moved with mouse,i want when ever the vertices be inside the box,to reset their position to the original position,and reconstruct the model,while the others dismorph. Always resetting the position when they are in the box,and move when they are not.Can anyone help me.Until now what it happens,is that when the vertices are inside the box they stop moving.

Thanks in Advance

```
import peasy.*;
import saito.objloader.*;


OBJModel model ;
OBJModel tmpmodel ;

PeasyCam cam;

float easing = 0.005;
float r;
float k =0.00001;
int VertCount;
PVector[] Verts;
PVector Mouse;

void setup()
{
  size(800, 800, P3D);
  frameRate(30);
  noStroke();

  model = new OBJModel(this, "Model2.obj", "absolute", TRIANGLES);
  model.enableDebug();
  model.scale(100);
  model.translateToCenter();

  tmpmodel = new OBJModel(this, "Model2.obj", "absolute", TRIANGLES);
  tmpmodel.enableDebug();
  tmpmodel.scale(100);
  tmpmodel.translateToCenter();



  cam = new PeasyCam(this, width/2, height/2, 0, 994);
}



void draw()
{
  background(129);
  lights();

  int VertCount = model.getVertexCount ();
  PVector[] Verts = new PVector[VertCount];
  PVector[] locas = new PVector[VertCount];
  float r =80;
  PVector Mouse = new PVector(mouseX-width/2, mouseY-height/2, 0);


  cam.setMouseControlled(true);










  //println(frameCount);
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2, height/2, 0);



  for (int i = 0; i < VertCount; i++) {
    //PVector orgv = model.getVertex(i);


    Verts[i]= model.getVertex(i);
    arrayCopy(Verts, locas);
    //PVector tmpv = new PVector();
    if (frameCount> 100) {



      float randX = random(-5, 5);
      float randY = random(-5, 5);
      float randZ = random(-5, 5);

      PVector Ran = new PVector(randX, randY, randZ);

      //float norX = abs(cos(k)) * randX;
      //float norY = abs(cos(k)) * randY;
      //float norZ = abs(cos(k)) * randZ;









      if (Verts[i].x > Mouse.x  - r/2 && Verts[i].x < Mouse.x  + r/2) {
        if (Verts[i].x > Mouse.y  - r/2 && Verts[i].x < Mouse.y  + r/2) {
          if (Verts[i].x > Mouse.z  - r/2 && Verts[i].x <  Mouse.z  + r/2) {


            arrayCopy(locas, Verts);
          }
        }
      } else {


        Verts[i].x+=Ran.x;
        Verts[i].y+=Ran.y;
        Verts[i].z+=Ran.z;

        if (Verts[i].x > width/2 || Verts[i].x < -width/2) {
          Verts[i].x+=-Ran.x;
        }
        if (Verts[i].y > height/2 || Verts[i].y < -height/2) {
          Verts[i].y+=-Ran.y;
        }
        if (Verts[i].z < -800/2 || Verts[i].z > 800/2) {  
          Verts[i].z+=-Ran.z;
        }
      }
      tmpmodel.setVertex(i, Verts[i].x, Verts[i].y, Verts[i].z);
    }
    k+=0.0001;
  }

  pushMatrix();
  translate(Mouse.x, Mouse.y, Mouse.z);
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  box(r);
  popMatrix();


  noStroke();

  tmpmodel.draw();

  popMatrix();



  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2, height/2, 0);
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  box(width, height, 600);
  popMatrix();
}
```

if you want to run it use the model from the saito obj example or the PshapeObj example.

Comment: Where are you getting the saito library? [Their homepage](https://code.google.com/p/saitoobjloade/) seems to be broken. In any case, can you get rid of it and post a [mcve] that doesn't use libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things about your code that don't make a ton of sense (some comments might have helped with that). Why are you copying the array like that?

In any case, I would start simpler if I were you. I would adopt an object oriented approach, where you create a class that encapsulates a point's original position as well as its current position.

Here's an example that does this in two dimensions, but this approach generalizes to three dimensions:

```
ArrayList<MovingPoint> points = new ArrayList<MovingPoint>();
float circleDiameter = 200;

void setup(){

  size(500, 500);

  for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    points.add(new MovingPoint());
  }
}


void draw(){

  background(0);

  noFill();
  stroke(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, circleDiameter, circleDiameter);

  fill(255);
  stroke(255);

  MovingPoint previousPoint = null;

  for(MovingPoint mp : points){

    mp.draw();

    if(previousPoint != null){
      line(previousPoint.current.x, previousPoint.current.y, mp.current.x, mp.current.y);
    }

    previousPoint = mp;
  }
}

class MovingPoint{
  PVector original;
  PVector current;

  public MovingPoint(){
    original = new PVector(random(width), random(height));
    current = original.copy();
  }

  void draw(){

    if(dist(current.x, current.y, mouseX, mouseY) < circleDiameter/2){
     //inside circle, reset position
     current = original.copy();
    }
    else{
      //outside circle, move randomly
      current.x += random(-5, 5);
      current.y += random(-5, 5);
    }

    ellipse(current.x, current.y, 10, 10);
  }
}
```

You shouldn't have to go through the rigmarole of copying arrays. Just use a class that remembers each point's original and current positions, and then switch between them depending on the mouse position.

If you still can't get it working, please post another question that works from this example instead of your entire sketch. It's hard to help if we don't have access to the libraries you're using, so you're better off getting rid of them and narrowing the problem down to as few lines as possible. Good luck.